# format on date in the order condition of a select in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have little experience with cakephp and I need to make a query with condition of order with format date `yyyy-mm-dd`.

now in the program is done like this:

```
$pagos = $this->Pago->find('all', array('recursive' => 1, 'conditions' => 
 $conditions, 'order' => array('Pago.fecha_asignacion' => 'ASC',  'Pago.monto_deposito' => 'DESC')));
```

and I need the format of the date in the order to be as I have it in
 this query:

```
SELECT * FROM pagos where estado_id = 2 order by DATE_FORMAT(fecha_asignacion, '%y %m %d') ASC, monto_deposito DESC
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Date columns are already ordered. You don't need to format your date column `fetcha_asignacion` before ordering. Wrapping it in a function will prevent the use of indexes, and not provide a different answer.

Comment: In the DB it is stored yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss so I need to only order under the criterion yyyy-mm-dd otherwise it contemplates the second in the order so it does not match correctly with the second criterion

Comment: so? if you order by date-time you've also ordered by date.

Comment: I explain it with an example:

Data sort by date (yy-mm-dd hh-mm) and amount

id1   2019-01-01 12:30:00       $400 
id2   2019-01-01 13:30:00       $200
id3   2019-01-01 14:30:00 $500
id4   2019-01-02 15:30:00 $100
id5   2019-01-02 16:30:00 $300

Data sort by date (yy-mm-dd) and amount


id3   2019-01-01    $500
id1   2019-01-01    $400 
id2   2019-01-01    $200
id4   2019-01-02    $300
id5   2019-01-02    $100

so I solved it:
.....array('Date(Pago.fecha_asignacion)' => 'ASC'.....

Thank you

Comment: ok. got it. Recommend a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html) with index to help this be a quick query.